# Implementing templated template method

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, template-method-pattern

Note: The following question is about the [*Template Method Design Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and **C++ function templates**. To distinguish both, I will use *italics* when referring to the design pattern and **bold** when referring to C++ templates.

The idea of the *template method pattern* is to make parts of an algorithm exchangeable. This is usually achieved via inheritance, where the subclass provides concrete implementations that are plugged into an algorithm of the base class. However, if the hook methods need to be **templates**, this will not work as **templates** cannot be virtual. Here is a simple example that does not compile:

```
class Base
{
public:

    // This is the template method
    template <typename T>
    void doSomething(T input)
    {
        //...
        auto converted = ConvertInput(input);
        //...
        std::cout << converted;
    }

protected:
    //compile error "member function templates cannot be virtual"
    template <typename T>
    virtual T ConvertInput(T input) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    template <typename T>
    T ConvertInput(T input)
    {
        return 2 * input;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.doSomething(3);
}
```

Is there a way to implement *template methods* that use **function template** hooks?

I am not interested in using the `Base` class as a type anywhere. I will always use the concrete specific type to achieve a maximum of compile-time optimization. So another formulation of this question is: How can I create several classes `Derived-1 .. Derived-n` that have **function templates** that share a common code skeleton across the implementations?

Comment: [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Make `Base` take `Derived` as a template parameter. Call `ConvertInput` via `static_cast<D*>(this)->ConvertInput`

Comment: Is there any limitation on the set of types used for `T`?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, but only implicit ones. E.g. one instance of this needs to take iterators, which could be anything.

Comment: @nico iteration can be type erased.  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a fine use-case for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Define `Base` as a class template with the type derived from it as the template parameter. Inside `Base`'s methods you can cast down to the derived type:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    // This is the template method
    template <typename T>
    void doSomething(T input)
    {
        //...
        auto converted = static_cast<Derived*>(this)->ConvertInput(input);
        //...
        std::cout << converted << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And then define the derived types, for example:

```
struct Square : Base<Square>
{
    template<typename T>
    auto ConvertInput(T t)
    {
        return t*t;
    }
};

struct Sum : Base<Sum>
{
    template<typename T>
    auto ConvertInput(T t)
    {
        return t+t;
    }
};
```

the usage is pretty trivial:

```
Square sq;
Sum sum;
sq.doSomething(3);
sum.doSomething(3);
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4VSEonxMUGqIB0yV)

Comment: Thanks. I already thought in this direction and it is definitely a possible solution. I would also be interested in solutions that do not require to make `Base` a class template.

Comment: +1 for CRTP: did not read past that.  If rest of post confuses you, just read up about CRTP, your problem is perfect for it.

Answer (score 3):

CRTP solves your problem by making Base a template.

If `T` comes from a finite set, or conversion is non arbutrary, type erasure can work.

If a finite set, type erase all the derived virtual methods.  If common property, type erase that property and virtualize method that acts on it.  Or a mixture.

Otherwise, Base can have template methods that take the operation as function object (with template `operator()`)  instead of using virtual to find it.  Derived passes the templated operations in as arguments to Base method(s).  This is basically CRTP without CRTP.